# Getting canonical path from Path in Java

Tags: java

I have a `Path` object, but it appears it does not have a `getCanonicalPath()` method like in the `File` class. Reason is I have dots in the Path that I want to eliminate to get something "unique":

```
/some/path/./something 
# should be
/some/path/something
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [normalize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#normalize%28%29) and [toRealPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toRealPath%28java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `getRealPath()` does the job. If not you can always call `path.toFile().getCanonicalPath()`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't try this but this seems appropriate:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#normalize%28%29